# Highcharts - Losing color when hovering over highlighted point

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I've made a feature using highcharts so i can highlight a point in a bar chart when is selected.

Currently i'm using this method to update the point color

```js
 point.graphic.attr({ fill: 'red' });
```

The result is what i'm expecting, but when I hover the highlighted point the color disappears and turns off.

https://jsfiddle.net/fog99ge6/

Before this, I was using this other method and worked perfectly

```js
point.color = 'red'; 
point.update(point.color)
```

but since there is 8 charts and they have lots of points each of them, my browser was freezing completely while the points were painted. Do you have any idea of how can i let the highlight color after the hover?

Comment: You should still use point.update() method, but with disabled redrawing - point.update(options, false, false) - after updating all points you should call chart.redraw().

Comment: Thanks! Now it works perfectly.